# SQL: Объединить результат запроса с другим результатом таблицы

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

Доброе время суток,
есть запрос:

```
select distinct n.ACCOUNTANCY_ID
from NC n
where n.DEVICE_ID in (
    select d.ID
    from DEVICES d
    where d.PROPOSAL_ID in (
        select distinct(ct.PROPOSAL_ID)
        from CROSS_T ct
        where ct.CONTRACT_ID in (
            select ct.CONTRACT_ID
            from CROSS_T ct
            where ct.PROPOSAL_ID in (
                select ct.PROPOSAL_ID
                from CROSS_T ct
                where ct.CONTRACT_ID = 49
            ) and ct.CONTRACT_ID is not null
        )
    ) and d.IN_ACCOUNTANCY = 2 and d.DEVICES_CL_ID <> -1
)
```

он выдает список *ID* строк, которые находятся в таблице «*ACCOUNTANCY*», но в этой таблице могут быть строки **не** со всеми *ID* (который выдает запрос).
***Вопрос***:
Как узнать количество строк, *ID* которых отсутсвуют в таблице «ACCOUNTANCY»?
Спасибо за ответ.
P.S.:
Самое банальное решение сделать 2 запроса, первый: запрос - который представлен выше, второй: запрос:

```
select count(distinct a.ACT_NUMBER)
    from ACCOUNTANCY a
      where a.ID in (‘запрос который представлен выше’)
```

затем сделать вычитание…
но это кажется не совсем правильно.
Можно было бы сделать каккой-нибудь "left join" например, но результат с таблицы, и результат запроса, не очень то "джоинятся".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся эта лесенка почти наверняка может быть переписана при помощи JOIN и без операторов DISTINCT.

Отвечая на вопрос, пусть результат этого сложного запроса - это некая таблица `t` с полем `accountancy_id`

В этом случае, чтобы узнать количество элементов `accountancy_id`, отсутствующих в таблице `accountancy`, используем такой запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM accountancy
RIGHT JOIN t
ON accountancy.id = t.accountancy_id
WHERE accountancy.id IS NULL
```

`RIGHT JOIN` выбирает все элементы из таблицы `t` и только подходящие элементы из таблицы `accountancy`. Соответственно, вместо неподходящих будут значения NULL

Пример на [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f476a/1)

Запрос можно вписать вот так:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM accountancy
RIGHT JOIN (
   select distinct n.ACCOUNTANCY_ID
   ...
) t
ON accountancy.id = t.accountancy_id
WHERE accountancy.id IS NULL
```

Comment: да, я был близко...к ответу, только с "left join" промашка и у меня почему-то к второму запросу не мог обратиться как к таблице, была ошибка. ну да ладно. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: А подскажите пожалуйста по этому запросу: Дело в том, что в если в таблице "*ACCOUNTANCY*" нет строк удовлетворяющих условию (*ON a.ID = t.ACCOUNTANCY_ID*), и запрос с (*join...* ) выдает "*null*", то результатом конечно будет "*0*", оно правда так, но мне бы хотелось в этом случае получить не "*0*", а "**null**"